# Prove APY formula with the function for compounding interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have two very similar formulas and I need to use one to prove the other.  The example I am using I found in the back of the book for a similar problem.  Here are the two formulas $$APY=(1+\frac r{12})^{12} -1$$ $$A(t)=P(1+\frac rn)^{n*t}$$

- APY(Annual Percent Yield)
- A(t) is the compounding interest function.

I'd like to know what $a$ is in the example below using these two formulas? I think $(a = 1)$:$$APY= \frac{A(t)-a}{a}$$  In the APY formula the -1 is replaced with-a.  This is why I'd think $(a=1)$.$$APY= \frac{a[(1+ \frac r{12})-a]}{a}$$

If a = 1 and P = a then it holds true, but if P $ \neq$ 1 then the proof cannot work?  The rest of the example is $$(1+ \frac r{12})^{12}-1$$ $$I(n)=(1 + \frac rn)^n-1$$

I am really not sure why they are using a instead of 1?  Is it because they needed away to drop P (the initial value) before compounding to come up with the new function?

Comment: What is the book you have been using ?

Comment: Pre-calculus openstax from Rice University.  It is free on Kindle.  I seem to have skipped this problem.  I guess I need to go back and find the question.